# Short story about a passenger and taxi driver who somehow travel through time to the late 1800s

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, time-travel

I'm looking for a short story as part of a collection of short stories that was about a passenger and taxi driver who somehow travel through time to the late 1800s.  They run into native Americans and I think the taxi driver is killed.  It's a humorous story and the book came out probably in the mid to late 1980s.  Thanks for your help.